How to Handle Cache Invalidation in Redis When Query Predicates Change in a Paging System
I'm working on a system where I cache paginated results using Redis. The caching logic stores data for the current page, the next page, and the page after that. Each page's cache key is based on the page index and a hash of the query predicate.
The problem arises when the query predicate changes. I need to ensure that the cache reflects the new predicate’s results and that any old cache entries related to the previous predicate are invalidated.
Specifically, I have implemented a cache system that handles:
Storing data for the current page and the next two pages.
Generating cache keys based on the page index and a hash of the query predicate.
My codes are below to help you.
    public class GetDataPagedListQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetDataPagedListQueryRequest, OptResult<PaginatedList<GetDataPagedListQueryResponse>>>
    {
        private readonly IDepartmentService _departmentService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public GetDataPagedListQueryHandler(IDepartmentService departmentService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _departmentService = departmentService;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<OptResult<PaginatedList<GetDataPagedListQueryResponse>>> Handle(GetDataPagedListQueryRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await ExceptionHandler.HandleOptResultAsync(async () =>
            {
                var model = _mapper.Map<GetAllPaged_Index_Dto>(request);

                var result = await _departmentService.GetDataPagedForDepartment(model);

                var response = _mapper.Map<PaginatedList<GetDataPagedListQueryResponse>>(result.Data);

                if (response != null) 
                    return await OptResult<PaginatedList<GetDataPagedListQueryResponse>>.SuccessAsync(response, Messages.Successfull);
                return await OptResult<PaginatedList<GetDataPagedListQueryResponse>>.FailureAsync(Messages.UnSuccessfull);
            });
        }
    }
}

[Service(ServiceLifetime.Scoped)]
    public class DepartmentService : IDepartmentService
    {
        private readonly IDepartmentReadRepository _readRepository;
        private readonly IDepartmentWriteRepository _writeRepository;
        private readonly DepartmentSpecifications _departmentSpecifications;
        private readonly IRedisCacheService _redisCacheService;

        public DepartmentService(IDepartmentReadRepository readRepository, IDepartmentWriteRepository writeRepository, DepartmentSpecifications departmentSpecifications, IRedisCacheService redisCacheService)
        {
            _readRepository = readRepository;
            _writeRepository = writeRepository;
            _departmentSpecifications = departmentSpecifications;
            _redisCacheService = redisCacheService;
        }
public async Task<OptResult<PaginatedList<Department>>> GetDataPagedForDepartment(GetAllPaged_Index_Dto model)
        {
            var predicate = _departmentSpecifications.GetDataPagedListPredicate(model);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.OrderBy)) model.OrderBy = "DepartmentName ASC";

            PaginatedList<Department> pagedDepartments;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchText) || !_redisCacheService.IsConnected)
                pagedDepartments = await _readRepository.GetDataPagedAsync(predicate, "", model.PageIndex, model.Take, model.OrderBy);
            else
                pagedDepartments = await _redisCacheService.GetPaginatedListAsync("departments", model.PageIndex, async pageIndex =>
                   await _readRepository.GetDataPagedAsync(predicate, "", pageIndex, model.Take, model.OrderBy));

            return await OptResult<PaginatedList<Department>>.SuccessAsync(pagedDepartments, Messages.Successfull);
        }
    }
}

public class RedisCacheService : IRedisCacheService
    {
        private readonly IDatabase _database;
        private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;

        public RedisCacheService(IConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer)
        {
            _database = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
            _connectionMultiplexer = connectionMultiplexer;

        }
        public bool IsConnected => _connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected;
public async Task<PaginatedList<T>> GetPaginatedListAsync<T>(string cachePrefixName, int pageIndex, Func<int, Task<PaginatedList<T>>> data) where T : class
        {
            int minPageIndex = pageIndex;
            int maxPageIndex = pageIndex + 2;

            if (pageIndex >= 1)
            {
                int prevMaxPageIndex = minPageIndex - 1;
                int prevMinPageIndex = minPageIndex - 2;

                for (int i = prevMinPageIndex; i <= prevMaxPageIndex; i++)
                {
                    if (i >= 1)
                    {
                        string oldPageKey = $"{cachePrefixName}_{i}";
                        await DeleteAsync(oldPageKey);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = minPageIndex; i <= maxPageIndex; i++)
            {
                string pageKey = $"{cachePrefixName}_{i}";
                var cachedData = await GetAsync<PaginatedList<T>>(pageKey);
                if (cachedData == null)
                {
                    var pageData = await data(i);
                    if (pageData.Data.Count > 0)
                    {
                        await SetAsync(pageKey, pageData, TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
                    }
                }
            }
            string currentPageKey = $"{cachePrefixName}_{pageIndex}";
            return await GetAsync<PaginatedList<T>>(currentPageKey);
        }

What I Want to Achieve:
When a new query is executed with a different predicate, I want to ensure that the old cache entries are invalidated and new data is fetched from the database and cached based on the new predicate.
This involves clearing the cache for pages related to the old predicate and storing new pages as per the updated predicate.
What I've Tried:
I’ve used a hash of the predicate to create a unique cache key. However, I am unsure how to efficiently manage the cache invalidation when predicates change, especially how to handle cache entries for multiple pages that might be affected.
